# Express server code is running in terminal but not working

Tags: express

```
$ node index.js
(node:7516) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\Rutuja123\Desktop\Rutuja\Web Development\2.4 QR Code Project\Express server\index.js:1
import Express from "Express";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.17.0
```

I am making the server using Express but above error occurs.

Comment: _"set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension"_ - and read up on CommonJS vs. ES modules.

Comment: Express needs to be lower cased

Answer (score 0):

Add `"type" : "module"` in **package.json** to solve problem.

**Example : package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "test_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  }
}
```